# How to replace if(Optional.isPresent()) with an expression in functional style

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following block of code:

```
Optional<Integer> result = //some method that returns an Optional<Integer>;

    if(result.isPresent()) {
        return result.get();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
```

and my IntelliJ suggests that I replace it with a functional expression. I see that there is a method `ifPresentOrElse()` inside `Optional` but I can't possibly figure out how to use it in this particular case.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Use InteliJ IDE - it gives many hints about code style.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like `orElse()` is what you'd want here. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-

```
Optional<Integer> result = //some method that returns an Optional<Integer>;
return result.orElse(0);
```